# Hysteresis measurement voltage behaviour

Tags: voltage, measurement, hysteresis

I am currently doing a hysteresis measurement using the below depicted measurement setup, however with different values.
[image: Hysteresis Measurement Setup]

The odd thing is that I have different VM2 values, depending on how I connect +- of the voltage source to the left circuit.
[image: The blue is VM2]
[image: Thats the result if connections are switched]
Since I am dealing with an AC voltage, it does not make sense for me.
Does anyone know, why VM2 changes (not only its phase, but also its amplitude)?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not a synchro problem with the scope?

Comment: Yes, I am nearly sure. If you look closely, you can also see the difference in the blue signals' amplitude.